# How can I validate if a 13.10 update was complete?

Tags: upgrade

I attempted to upgrade Ubuntu 13.04 server to 13.10 tonight via the standard linux text console and it had some trouble. Machine boots and displays 13.10, but I am unsure exactly what or how much was successfully upgraded.

Is there some command I can run which will validate that all system has all standard binaries upgraded to the 13.10 release?

As for the issue .... everything seemed to be going along ok until the screen displayed some kind of menu option regarding local edits to samba config file. There was a prompt requesting root password or ctrl-d to continue, but it would not take any input. From another terminal screen I tried killing the process displaying this samba message, and then some screen/SCREEN processes. The hard drive activity picked up for a while and then all the processes on that pty were gone. As I said, reboot was OK, but I have no idea if everything was upgraded. The machine seems to be acting like normal, except that the upgrade killed my openpvn process which I'll need to reload.

Thanks

Comment: "no input was taken" - I used to think that too, but actually when typing a password in the terminal, it just doesn't show up for security. For next time, remember that! ;-)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please use the contact us link at the bottom of this page to ask for your unregistered account and your new registered account to be merged. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y; sudo apt-get install -f -y; sudo aptitude upgrade -y;
```

If all things check out, then you are fully upgraded.

Comment: Almost fixed I think. I had to run 'dpkg --configure -a' after this your first 3 apt-get's came up clean, but the 'apt-get aptitude upgrade -y' prints "E: Invalid operation aptitude".

Comment: I see, I meant to type sudo aptitude upgrade -y

Answer (score 1):

Thanks mmstick, all that helped. The final answer was to do the following:

```
apt-get update   # resulted in an error indicating dpkg --configure -a was needed
dpkg --configure -a   # seemed to fix a lot of stuff and re-invoke samba config question
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get dist-upgrade -y
apt-get install -f -y
aptitude upgrade -y
```

Looks like the dpkg did most of the correction.  The last 4 commands came up clean and system seems to be running fine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please use the contact us link at the bottom of this page to ask for your unregistered account and your new registered account to be merged. Thanks.